# ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'No result' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use this code for post data from ws.

service.ts

```
 public events(id: string): Observable<Events> {
    ......
    return this.http.post(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.events), body, {
      headers: headers
    })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();
        if (res.StatusCode === 0) {
          return res.StatusDescription;
               } else {
          return new Events(null);
        }
      });
  }
```

This code, show all my data, if ws doesn't get data, no result, this function show error:
*`ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'No result' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`*

For display in page I used this code:

```
event: Events;
  events: Events[]=[];

  getalleventsserial() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        this.ns.events(params['id']).subscribe(
          events => {
            this.event = events;
         }
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

html code:

```
<table *ngFor="let item of event">
<tr>
<td>{{item.id}}</td>
<td>{{item.alarmnr}}</td>
<td>{{item.name}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Please, can you suggest haw to solution this issue. Thnx

Comment: Yes, but when I use as you say, in page doesn't show any data. I tried this

Comment: No, isn't import because event: Events; and  events: Events[]=[];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose when there is no data for event, you service is returning the string `'No result'`, then make that condition for the `*ngIf`.

Use `*ngIf` to display event when it has data:

```
<table *ngIf="isEmpty">
  <tr *ngFor="let item of event">
    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
    <td>{{item.alarmnr}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

on **your.component**

```
event: Events;
events: Events[]=[];
isEmpty: boolean;

getalleventsserial() {
  this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
    params => {
      this.ns.events(params['id']).subscribe(
        events => {
          this.event = events;
          this.isEmpty = (Array.isArray(this.event)) ? true : false;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute named 'template' or prefixed with * ("

Comment: Nothing changes, is pretense this error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'No result' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Comment: Check again please !

Comment: Sorry again. Now, when I write command ng build --prod in this *ngIf="event != 'No result'" show this error: Operator '!=' cannot be applied to types 'Events' and 'string'.

Comment: Thanx you again